# wxWidgets Overlay Text (C++)

Tags: c++, overlay, wxwidgets

I am trying to place some overlay text over a wxPanel.
I have several panels with completely different Content but I want to place this overlay text over all of these panels in the top right Corner of the panel.
I am restricted to wxWidgets 2.8.12..
Do you see any way to achieve this behaviour?

Edit:
Here a bit more detailed Version of what I am trying to do:
[image: Layout with 5 containers]

I have a Layout that consists of e.g. 5 containers and each container can contain a module. A module can be either wxPanels that contain Plain text or Input controls or for example a OpenGL canvas or an Image or something else.

Because I have much content and it does not fit on a single page I want to make the modules inside a Container exchangeable. It would be also nice if the user is able to perform this action only by using its keyboard. E.g. if he presses the key "3" the content of the third container has to be switched.

To handle these shortcuts isn't a problem. However I need to signalize to the user the identifier / hotkey of the containers.
I could do this by placing a additional headline above each container, but I want to waste as little space as possible on the gui.
I also could draw directly to the modules content, but I would have to do this for every module and every module is designed in a different way (images, multi column, opengl, ...) and maybe even by different persons.

So I am looking for a simple solution to indicate the number of these containers that does not consume that much space.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gustav-Cams, which platform/toolkit? Do you use C++ or wxPython? Did you look at the samples for the library?

Comment: I use the C++ version in Visual Studio 2012. I also looked in the examples but I have no idea what to look for. A full-text search for "overlay" gave no results.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I.e. what did you try and what didn't work? There is, of course, no special need for any kind of "overlay", you can just put some text on any panel...

Comment: hi, I just updated my original post to provide a bit more information about my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wxWindowDC to draw anywhere on the window, even on child windows. However anything you draw will be painted over whenever the windows or controls repaint themselves. You can draw your overlay in an UpdateUI event handler to minimize this. I have used this approach with success on Windows with wxWidgets 2.8.12. Not sure if it works with OpenGL though.